# The view Project.views.profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, database

For my Django project, I have this view in my `views.py`:

```py
def profile(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            pass
        else:
            return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

I receive an error because the view didn't return an `HttpResponse` object. It returned `None` instead.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please format your code and provide more explanation of what is not working/expected

Comment: instead of `pass`, return a http response.

Answer (score 1):

```
def profile(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, '<Your html file what should render if user is authenticated>')
        else:
            return render(request, 'profile.html')
```